# jQuery get form data for only visible fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my `form` I got both visible and non-visible (`display:none`) elements. I need to get form data for only visible fields. I am collecting the data with the following code:

```
var formData = $('#myForm')
               .serializeArray()
               .reduce(function(obj, item) {   
                    //need to process only visible fields somewhere here                     
                    obj[item.name] = item.value;
                    return obj;
                }, {});
```

I know about disabling the `name` propery of the input, but after the data is collected, I would like to return this property for all fields back. Any ideas would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure, you can try `$('#myForm :visible')`

Comment: $("#myForm :visible").each(function(){
  console.log(this);
});

Comment: It worked, make it as an answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#myForm :visible").each(function(){
  console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to filter out hidden elements:

```js
function showValues() {
    var fields = $("form :input:visible").serializeArray();
    $("#results").empty();
    $.each(fields, function( i, field ) {
      $("#results").append( field.value + " " );
    });
  }
 
  $(":checkbox, :radio").click(showValues);
  $(":text").blur(showValues);
  $( "select" ).change(showValues);
  
  showValues();
```

```css
  body, select {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  form {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  p {
    color: red;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><b>Results:</b> <span id="results"></span></p>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text1" value="text1" id="text1"/>
  <input type="text" name="text2" value="text2" id="text2" style="display:none;"/>
  <select name="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1" />
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2" />
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>
```